# Get full path from relative path in maven

Tags: maven, path, exec-maven-plugin

I'm using the exec-maven-plugin in order to execute a non java file and pass another file as an argument.
I need to be able to use a full path which is on **top** of the ${basedir} directory.
How can I access such a directory without using the full path?

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
    <executable>[Path to my .exe file]</executable
        <argument>${basedir}\..\..\somedir\anotherdir</argument>
    <arguments>
```

Using the below code doesn't work and outputs the following cmd argument-

```
"c:\dir1\dir2\dir3\mybasedir..\..\somedir\anotherdir"
```

which is off course meaningless as a command line argument.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot a separator: `${basedir}\..\..\somedir\anotherdir`

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't help. Path still appears as the full string instead of the relative path...

Comment: Why do you care what the path looks like? Explain "full string" vs. "relative path". How does the above not work?

Comment: Ryan, you are correct. I indeed forgot the separator when trying to pass the relative path. Thanks for your time!